# Image and video previews in admin inline forms for ManyToMany relation

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

A have 3 models: Project, Image and Video with ManyToManyField relation:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    images = models.ManyToManyField('Image', through='Project_Images')
    video = models.ManyToManyField('Video', through='Project_Video')

class Image(models.Model):
    original = models.ImageField()
    projects = models.ManyToManyField('Project', through='Project_Images')

class Video(models.Model):
    projects = models.ManyToManyField('Project', through='Project_Video')
```

I configure project's admin form with inline forms of Images and Videos linked to current project:

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [VideoInline, ImagesInline]

class ImagesInline(admin.TabularInline):    
    model = Project_Images
    raw_id_fields = ['project','image']

class VideoInline(admin.TabularInline):    
    model = Project_Video
    raw_id_fields = ['project','video']
```

But inline table with simple select field and delete checkbox is much miserable for me, and I want to show here previews of images or video (youtube). I solve this for images with help of [AdminImageWidget](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/934/):

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image

    preview = forms.ImageField(widget=AdminImageWidget())
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            image = Image.objects.get(id=self.instance.image_id)
            self.fields["preview"].initial = image.original
        except:
            pass

class ImagesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    .....
    form = ImageForm
```

Is it best way to do this? In my case I don't need file upload input, only image-preview in inline form table. I need also preview for youtube video, should I write my own widget for displaying video and apply it to some fake field ?

It's strange to solve this issue by widget for unnecessary fake field. Or is it normal way?

Any help will be very much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: By the way, there's no need to set up ManyToManyField's both directions.  The ManyToManyField automatically sets up a "reverse relation" attribute on the "far" model, which you can set with the "related_name" attribute.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a widget similar to AdminImageWidget but that displays only the image, not the upload box.  To apply that widget you don't need a custom Form class or a fake field, just use formfield_overrides on your ImageInline:

```
class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    ...
    formfield_overrides = { models.ImageField: {'widget': YourPreviewWidget}}
```

**EDIT**: Oops, didn't fully process the ManyToManyField issue - you're displaying inlines for the "through" table, not the table with the actual ImageFields.  Given that, what you're doing now may be not such a bad solution.  The alternative I can think of would be to write a specialized replacement widget for the Select, that knows how to display both the select box and a preview image for the currently selected Image object.  That way you could avoid  the need for the fake extra field.

Comment: But I use ManyToMany relation! It's very important! I have only LINKS to real Image and Video objects in form inlines. I haven't any ImageFields inside these link objects.

Comment: What do you recomend to do in this case?